# Как оформляются названия машин

Tags: прописная-строчная, названия

*Наконец между огромным синим внедорожником и крошечной серебристой «Хондой» нашелся зазор, где удалось протиснуться бочком.*

Правильно ли писать название с заглавной буквы?

Answer (score 2):

[**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8)

> Справочники рекомендуют писать названия марок автомобилей в кавычках с прописной буквы: *автомобили «Волга», «Вольво», «Ниссан», «Шкода»*, а названия самих автомобилей как технических изделий – со строчной буквы в кавычках (кроме названий, совпадающих с собственными именами – личными и географическими). Например: *«кадиллак», «москвич», «тойота», «ниссан»*,  но: *«Волга», «Ока»* (совпадают с именами собственными, поэтому пишутся с большой буквы). Исключения: *«жигули», «мерседес»* (совпадают с именами собственными, но пишутся со строчной). Однако на практике различить, в каком случае наименование представляет собой название марки автомобиля, а в каком – наименование технического изделия, часто представляется затруднительным: *Всем автомобилям он предпочитает «Тойоту» / «тойоту»*. В спорных случаях решение о написании с прописной или строчной буквы принимает автор текста.
>
> В бытовом употреблении названия средств передвижения пишутся без кавычек, например: *Приехал на стареньком москвиче (на роскошном кадиллаке)*. Без кавычек пишутся также разговорные названия машин с уменьшительно-ласкательными суффиксами, напр.: *москвичок, фордик, уазик*.

В данном предложении, скорее всего, подходит вариант со строчной буквой. Также допускаю, что без кавычек тоже не ошибка: "*...крошечной серебристой хондой...*"